# While integrating LinkedIn can we import api key from web.config?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, linkedin-api

I have integrated loigin and registration functionality through LinkedIn, for this I have integrated LinkedIn APIs by using below code.

```
 <script src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript">
    api_key: MY_API_KEY
    onLoad: onLinkedInLoad
    authorize: false
    credentials_cookie: true
</script>
```

By using this code for every time when I switch my site to another server I have to change the API key in the script.
To resolve this, can we import the API key from web.config file?

Comment: If you use cshtml, you can easily add @Settings.Default.LinkedInAPIKey in the script.

Comment: its is, but I need to do it in c#.